# Netbeans: GUI builder with JTree

Tags: java, netbeans, jtree

I am creating a JTree using the GUI builder in Netbeans and I can add nodes and everything to the tree using the following code

```
public static void listAllFiles(String directory, DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Boolean recursive) {
            File [] children = new File(directory).listFiles(); // list all the files in the directory
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { // loop through each
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(children[i].getName());
                    // only display the node if it isn't a folder, and if this is a recursive call
                    if (children[i].isDirectory() && recursive) {
                            parent.add(node); // add as a child node
                            listAllFiles(children[i].getPath(), node, recursive); // call again for the subdirectory
                    } else if (!children[i].isDirectory()){ // otherwise, if it isn't a directory
                            parent.add(node); // add it as a node and do nothing else
                    }
            }
    }
```

then calling it like

```
listAllFiles("C:\\test",  defaultMutableTreeNode , true);
```

I can add this code to the `init()` method of the JTree so that when it is built it will have all the folders and files in the Test folder which is grand out, but what i really want to do is add the nodes to the JTree when i click on a button but i cant figure out how to do this! I can add the `listAllFiles("C:\\test",  defaultMutableTreeNode , true);` to the `ActionPerformed` of the a new button but then it cannot find the `defaultMutableTreeNode`.

So how would be the best way to do this? would it be to create a new `DefaultMutableTreeNode` when ever I click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figured out one way to do it but im not too sure if is the best way to do it! I basically create a new DefaultMutableTreeNode in the ActionPerformed of the button and that is populating the tree correctly for me anyway

```
javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode1 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
jTree.setModel(new javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel(treeNode1));
listAllFiles(folderPath,  treeNode1, true);
```

but would like to see if there is any better ways to do this... coding wise